# Swift 5.0 Generate subset of object array

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swift5

I have a struct model called Questions stored in DataRep which is also stored in EnvironmentObject. There are 100+ questions in 12 categories.

```
struct Question: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var questionText: String
    var questionComment: String
    var category: String

}
class DataRep: ObservableObject  {
    @Published var QuestionList : [Question] = QuestionListData
    @Published var selectedCategory = "all"
}
```

On the user interface, I placed 12 buttons at top and list view down to list the questions in that category.

When user clicks on a new category, I update the `selectedCategory` parameter and filter the main questions list object to select the relevant questions.

```
struct QuestionList: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var datarep: DataRep

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form {          
                ForEach(self.filterQuestions(datarep.QuestionList)) { question in
                    HStack{
                         QuestionView (question: question)
                    }
                }

            }//List
                .navigationBarTitle(self.datarep.selectedCategory )
                .labelsHidden()
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
}

    func filterQuestions(_ activeList : [Question]) -> [Question]
    {
        if self.datarep.selectedCategory != "all" {
            return activeList.filter{ $0.category.contains(self.datarep.selectedCategory) }
        }
        return  activeList
    }
}
```

However I am running into issues with filter method as it is generating a new array each time category is changed. There is no way I know to create a binding.

any suggestions?

Regards,
M

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `QuestionView` will take binding (to change the question), as

```
struct QuestionView: View {
    @Binding var question: Question
    ...
```

it can be bound (even after filtering) via main container like following

```
ForEach(self.filterQuestions(datarep.QuestionList)) { question in
    HStack{
         QuestionView (question: 
             self.$datarep.QuestionList[self.datarep.QuestionList.firstIndex(of: question)!])
    }
}
```